# Why does the 0 represent in java.lang.Class.forName0?

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace

I'm familiar with the basic structure of Java exceptions, but for the first time I noticed an oddity with a Class.forName stacktrace:

```
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
...
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Why are there two forName instances mentioned, and what does the zero represent? Is this how stacktraces represent multiple methods of the same name with different signatures?

Comment: It doesn't represent anything, it's just an internal name for a `private` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the source code for this method has its visibility labeled as `private`.

```
/** Called after security check for system loader access checks have been made. */
private static native Class<?> forName0(String name, boolean initialize,
                                        ClassLoader loader,
                                        Class<?> caller)
    throws ClassNotFoundException;
```

This means that this class is not intended to be a part of the public-facing API and isn't something that you as a mere mortal should invoke directly.

Why the zero?  It's just a naming convention.  It'd also look strange if it overloaded `forName` since this isn't intended to be used outside of this particular class.

This naming convention is not bound to or tied to Java's libraries; you can use whatever name you wish to describe your internal, non-public API.

As an example, [`ArrayList` abandons this convention](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java?av=f#222) and uses the `Internal` marker instead for an internal method.

```
private void ensureCapacityInternal(int minCapacity) {
    ensureExplicitCapacity(calculateCapacity(elementData, minCapacity));
}
```

Comment: Neat! I was looking at the oracle docs and didn't see the method defined there - that makes sense since it's private.

Comment: Good explanation! You can find other naming schemas for internal methods (for example trailing "Impl" or "Internal" in case of `ArayList.ensureCapacity()`). The duplicate question points out that in case of the trailing 0 it is likely carried over from previous languages/systems to highlight native methods.

Comment: @MalteHartwig:  Yes, I was trying to jog my memory around having *not* seeing 0 in an internal Java class.  In my mind I believe they changed some of that convention around over the last fifteen years.  I'll add that in as an example of it just being a vanilla naming convention.